# python lxml etree.tostring() why \r has encoding to &#13;

Tags: python, lxml

I have tried to parse:

```py
    request = urllib2.Request(url="http://2012.qq.com/sports/")
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    content = response.read()
    uni_content = content.decode("gb2312", "ignore")
    tecent = uni_content.encode("utf-8")

    tecent_page = etree.HTML(tecent, parser=etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
    test_tags = tecent_page.xpath("/html/body/div[@class='page']/div[@class='layout']/div/div[@class='bd']/ul[@class='list']/li")

    for i, item in enumerate(test_tags):
        content = etree.tostring(item, encoding="utf-8", pretty_print=True)
        print content
```

why  result like this :

```html
<li class="item">&#13;
                        <a class="pic" href="http://2012.qq.com/sports/judo/index.htm" target="_blank"><img width="96" height="96" src="http://mat1.gtimg.com/2012/samanthasun/allevents/roudao.png" alt="柔道"/></a>&#13;
                        <p><a href="http://2012.qq.com/sports/judo/index.htm" target="_blank">柔道</a></p>&#13;
                        <p><a href="http://2012.qq.com/l/sports/judo/judochn/list2011079114946.htm" target="_blank">新闻</a> | <a href="http://2012.qq.com/l/photos/33xiangmu/roudao/list2011079115124.htm" target="_blank">图片</a> | <a href="http://2012.qq.com/l/video/xm/vjudo/list.htm" target="_blank">视频</a></p>&#13;
                    </li>&#13;
```

why does it have  `&#13;`?
There is `&#13;` in every line. why?

Answer (score 1):

Because the original document (http://2012.qq.com/sports/) has [CR+LF line breaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). [Carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) has code 13.

You can use simple workaround: `tecent = uni_content.encode("utf-8").replace('\r\n', '\n')`